# Passar parâmetro para janela modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parâmetros

Tenho um link que faz a chamada de uma modal bootstrap e preciso que quando este seja clicado, a janela modal seja aberta e nela seja carregado um dado que foi enviado como parâmetro pelo link.

O link e a chamada da modal é o seguinte:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

E esse é o código da janela modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input type="text" id="demo"  value="">                                               
                                            <h3> Conteúdo</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Você quer carregar o conteúdo de uma url "externa" dinamicamente em um modal? Onde está esse parâmetro, na url atual?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste link, ele fala sobre a utilização do .modal-content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Não especificamente. Na verdade como sou novo em programação WEB, nem sei qual caminho seguir.Deixa eu tentar explicar melhor. Por exemplo, caso fosse em páginas diferentes, poderia por exemplo enviar algo via url, e em outra página recuperar o valor que foi enviado utilizando o método GET do Php. Como a janela modal se encontra na mesma página do link que a chama, eu não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Se você quer só exibir uma informação que já está na página (url no seu caso), só adicione o conteúdo dentro da `<div class="modal-body">  Seu Conteúdo  </div>`. Só lembre de utilizar o seguinte meio para recuperar a informação:      `<?php
    $my_string = filter_input(INPUT_GET, ‘my_string’, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>` Fonte: (http://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/)  Espero que seja isso e eu não tenha entendido errado...

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo.

Comment: essa div da modal, está na mesma página do link que abre ela ?

Comment: Sim, a modal está na mesma página. Consegui resolver com o exemplo deste link :   http://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/ .